# save data to map while processing xslt dynamically

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I want to create dynamic map in xslt and populate the same based on some conditions in xslt, how can i do that ?
i can see examples of hardcoded map like below and stored in variable, but i don't want like that

```
<xsl:variable name="map">
            <map>
                <entry key="key-1">value1</entry>
                <entry key="key-2">value2</entry>
                <entry key="key-3">value3</entry>
            </map>
        </xsl:variable>
```

Comment: An XSLT 3 map would be created with `xsl:map`.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the XSLT 3 spec in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-map is the example

```
<xsl:variable name="index" as="map(xs:string, element(employee))">
  <xsl:map>
    <xsl:for-each select="//employee">
      <xsl:map-entry key="@empNr" select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:map>
</xsl:variable>
```

It seems, however, that this gives a type error unless the input is schema validated so for untyped XML or not schema-aware XSLT you would need to redefine the map type or change the code a bit, the second option is shown below:

```
    <xsl:variable name="index" as="map(xs:string, element(employee))">
      <xsl:map>
        <xsl:for-each select="//employee">
          <xsl:map-entry key="string(@empNr)" select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:map>
    </xsl:variable>
```

Example fiddle is at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MP42MS.